# how to remove space between textarea and parent div

Tags: html, css

I have the following form which contains a textarea as shown:

[image]

As you can see there is a space between the blue shaded area and the bottom of the parent div.

How can I remove this space?

html:

```
    <div class="bottomBox">
        <h3>Free Quote Form</h3>
        <form class="freeQuoteForm" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="formFields">
                <input type="text" id="firstName" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="firstName">First Name</label><input type="text" id="lastName" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="LastName">Last Name</label>

            </div>
            <div class="formFields">
                <input type="email" id="email" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="email">Email Address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="formFields">
                <textarea rows="12" cols="50" id="sampleText" wrap="hard" class="input" required></textarea><label class="formLabel" for="sampleText">Please include a 1000 word sample from your document.</label>
        </form>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.bottomBox {
    background: white;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 640px;
    height: 700px;
    border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    animation: fadeIn 1.5s forwards, slideUpBottom 0.75s forwards;
}

.bottomBox h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.freeQuoteForm {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 530px;
    height: 550px;
    border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    text-align: left;
}

.formFields {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    position: relative;
}

.input {
    font-family: "Sinkin Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    padding-left: 12px;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.input:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}


.formLabel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    font-size: 70%;
    line-height: 8em;
    padding-left: 5px; 
    height: 3px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center left; 
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s ease forwards;
}

#lastName { border-left: 1px solid #9c9c9c; }

#lastName + .formLabel { left: 52%; }

#email, #sampleText { width: 100%; }

#sampleText {
    height: 350px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    overflow: scroll;
    resize: none;
}

#sampleText + .formLabel {
    top: -6px;
}

.input:focus {
    outline:none;
    background-color: #e6f9ff;
}

.input:focus + .formLabel {
    -webkit-animation: colorScaleMove 0.75s ease-in-out forwards;
}


.input:valid + .formLabel { 
    -webkit-animation: colorScaleMoveGrey 0s ease forwards;  
}

#sampleText:valid + .formLabel {
    animation: fadeOut 0s ease forwards;
}
```

Comment: just remove the height from `.freeQuoteForm`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue happens because block-level elements are aligned by the baseline (like text) by default. To fix it just set #sampleText `vertical-align: top;` or `vertical-align: bottom;`. I also recommend you to let its `overflow: auto;`

Demo: [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwwWjb)

Comment: @chell, did it really work for you? If it is then make me clear where did i wrong?

Comment: @chell remove the `label` tags and use `placeholder` instead. Example: `<input type="text" id="firstName" class="input" placeholder="First Name" required>`

Comment: Thank you so much! No idea how else I would have figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the height from `.freeQuoteForm`. Cause its fixed the parent div height to a fixed portion. So free the height, it will take the height auto as the child need.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/uwnv5ubk/1/)

**Updated CSS Block:**

```
.freeQuoteForm {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 530px;
    border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Updated HTML:**

```
<div class="bottomBox">
  <h3>Free Quote Form</h3>
  <form class="freeQuoteForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="formFields">
      <input type="text" id="firstName" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="firstName">First Name</label><input type="text" id="lastName" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="LastName">Last Name</label>

    </div>
    <div class="formFields">
      <input type="email" id="email" class="input" required><label class="formLabel" for="email">Email Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="formFields">
      <textarea rows="12" cols="50" id="sampleText" wrap="hard" class="input" required></textarea>
      <label class="formLabel" for="sampleText">Please include a 1000 word sample from your document.</label>
     </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

> You miss to put the div in the last child of div, which is the parent
>   of `textarea`.

Comment: I tried this but I still had a space between the blue fill and the bottom of the box. Thanks for pointing out the missing close div tag.

Comment: did you see the fiddle?